# C# - programmatically identify relationship type between 2 tables

Tags: c#, orm

Currently using **GetOleDbSchemaTable** to tell me a lot of information about my database tables. While the **OleDbSchemaGuid.Foreign_Keys** argument tells me about the foreign key data on a table I cannot infer if something is 1:N, N:1, N:M etc from this data. Is there any way I can derive this type of information?

Comment: Can you determine if the column(s) which the foreign key reference(s) form a unique index on the referenced table?  If you can then you can make a deduction.

Answer (score 1):

As Jack commented you can know if the schema returns the unique property of the column.

if the foreign key from table A is unique in table B then its a 1 to 1 relation.

if it has a unique  constraint in table B with the primary key in table B, then its 1 to many.

if there is a table C between A and B where both A\B primaries are foreign keys in C then its a many to many relation.